# Amazon EC2 Error or Application Error - swapon: /dev/sda3: read swap header failed

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-503

Can anyone tell me what this error is?  Is this an Amazon EC2 related error?

Our application is hosted on Amazon EC2 and when we try to hit the site we are getting a blank page with 503 error.

There is nothing unusual other than the error we located on the Amazon System report.

swapon: /dev/sda3: read swap header failed: Invalid argument

mountall: swapon /dev/sda3 449 terminated with status 255

mountall: Problem activating swap: /dev/sda3

```
Asking all remaining processes to terminate...
```

[80G init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor

init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor

init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor

init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor

Answer (score 0):

Its reading like a disk failure. If you were using instance storage, you should be restoring from backups. If you were using EBS volumes, you will need to restore from a snapshot.